# SQL - MVC - Insert into 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

im working in mvc and use sql command to insert data to my
database.

what i try to do is insert into 2 tables which one of them
have the foreign key from the other.

how can i build my sql query to make a condition on insert 
into the table Image, insert the id in the foreignkey column
in the table Content.

```
 using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
    SqlCommand cmd;
    System.Text.StringBuilder sql = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sql.Append("insert into Image(FileName)");
    sql.Append("values (@FileName)");

    SqlCommand cmd2;
    System.Text.StringBuilder sql2 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sql.Append("insert into Code(Html,JsCode,Id_Img)");
    sql.Append("values (@Html, @JsCode, @Id_Img)");

    cn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), cn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = myfilename;
    int FileId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2.ToString(), cn);
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Html", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mydiv;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@JsCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Id_Img", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FileId;
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
 cn.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `ExecuteScalar()` instead `ExecuteNonQuery()` to get the `Scope_identity()` value from the server like below and add that FileId to the second query.

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("your_connection_string"))
{
    string sql1 = "insert into Image(FileName) values (@FileName); " +
                  "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)"; 

    string sql2 = "insert into Code(Html,JsCode,Id_Img) values (@Html, @JsCode, @Id_Img)";  

    int FileId = 0;

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1,cn))
    {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", myfilename);
         cn.Open();
         FileId= (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

}
```

Comment: i have try it but i get this error now: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Where are you setting the connection? Can you check your cn object?

Comment: Check my edit post, in your update I can't notice anything wrong other than you have opened the connection before creating the command.

Comment: I try it Kaf, but i get the same error at FileId= (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: the connection are open and the value are 0

Comment: the ExecuteScalar does not exists in the current context

Comment: What is your db server? mysql or sql-server

Comment: Kaf its working now.. Perfect!!! I have try it with the Select Cast etc... in the sql1 string  and now its working perfectly.. Thank you very much..  if i could i would give you more than +1..  Thanks

Comment: I think the reason is `ExcuteScalar() returns the first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference if the result set is empty`. Since you didn't have that `Select query after the insert` it returned null..., Good luck !

Comment: scope_identity() has some potential issues that are well-documented on MSDN.